# Spring JPA - JPQL Named Query Find All By Year And And month

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get all objects by specific month and year.
I have done this with Native Query

```
   @Query(value = "select * from transaction_log as t where year(t.insurance_period)=(:year) AND user_id =(:userId) AND t.employer_id is null", nativeQuery = true)
```

And I want to be done with another way so I can use entity graphs etc.
I have try

```
@Query("select t from Transaction t where year(t.insuranceDate) = ?1 and month(t.insuranceDate) = ?2")
```

And I get error on method Year () for unexcepted '('

and the following with the same error at EXTRACT method.

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM t.insuranceDate) = :year AND EXTRACT (month FROMt.insuranceDate) = :month")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `BETWEEN` first day of month and last day of month. According to [jpql doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_between) `BETWEEN` is inclusive.

The downside is doing some date calculations, but they are trivial with `java.time` classes. Let's say you want dates from February 2020. You could get first and last day like this:

```
int year = 2020;
int month = 2;
LocalDate firstDay = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
LocalDate lastDay = firstDay.withDayOfMonth(firstDay.lengthOfMonth());
```

Then the query will look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE t.insuranceDate BETWEEN :firstDay AND :lastDay")
```